# ERROR::TEXTURECACHE:Failed to load in JetBrains CLion

Tags: c++, clion, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to make a Breakout game in JetBrains CLion and I keep getting the `ERROR::TEXTURECACHE:Failed to load` for three of my objects (ball, paddle and brick). I can't seem to find the problem, nor can anyone else I know, so I thought I'd come on here and see if anyone has any ideas to fix it.

*My sprites are in the correct positions. My sprites and their positions are all correct.

(Example of image referencing)

```
bool Breakout::init()
{
  setupResolution();
  if (!initAPI())
  {
    return false;
  }

  toggleFPS();

  renderer->setClearColour(ASGE::COLOURS::NAVY);

  // input handling functions
  inputs->use_threads = false;

  key_callback_id =
    inputs->addCallbackFnc(ASGE::E_KEY, &Breakout::keyHandler, this);

  mouse_callback_id =
    inputs->addCallbackFnc(ASGE::E_MOUSE_CLICK, &Breakout::clickHandler, this);

  block.initialiseSprite(renderer.get(),
                         "data/images/element_red_rectangle.png");

  paddle.initialiseSprite(renderer.get(), "data/images/paddleRed.png");
  paddle.changeSize(32, 128);

  return true;
}
```

Comment: It's easier to spot the problem if you present a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be related to CLion itself. Perhaps it could be seen as a CLion problem because you might need to set the current working directory of the program in the "Run" settings?

Comment: Some programmer dude. I've had this problem for a while and you just fixed it within 10 minutes of me asking. not even my lecturer could fix it. I know, slightly worrying. Thank youu

Comment: @Parzival55 If that resolved your issue then think on improving your code a bit: instead or using relative file paths like you do right now (that rely on current working folder and most likely will fail if program is launched from another folder) consider calculating and using the full file path to your resources (e.g. instead of `paddle.initialiseSprite(renderer.get(), "data/images/paddleRed.png");` do something like `paddle.initialiseSprite(renderer.get(), getFullResourcePath("data/images/paddleRed.png"));` where `getFullResourcePath` will be your function that makes such absolute/full path.